# poll/monitor a linux command's output

Tags: command-line-interface, linux

Is there a way to monitor the output of a linux command without having to type it over and over.

I want to do something like:

```
tail -f file.txt
```

But for a command like:

```
ps aux | grep httpd | wc
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
watch 'ps aux | grep httpd | wc'
```

Comment: `-n 0.1` switch to `watch` can be really useful for fast-changing data

Answer (score 2):

```
while true
do
  ps aux | grep httpd | wc
  sleep 10
done
```